# I can not make the event work only once (BeaconManager.RangingListener())

Tags: android, estimote

I use in my Projects `Estimote/Android-SDK`and I have a problem.
at a time when I come to the Beacon in the area `Proximity.IMMEDIATE` I send a request to the server, which rotates the result of me.

```
beaconManager.setRangingListener(new BeaconManager.RangingListener() {
            @Override
            public void onBeaconsDiscovered(final Region region, final List<Beacon> beacons) {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        getSupportActionBar().setSubtitle("Found beacons: " + beacons.size());
                        adapter.replaceWith(beacons);
                        for (Beacon beacon : beacons){
                            if (beacon.getMinor()==22222 && Utils.computeProximity(beacon)== Utils.Proximity.IMMEDIATE){
                                String android_id = Settings.Secure.getString(context.getContentResolver(),
                                        Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
                                UserApiConnector.me().getQueue(android_id);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

and it works.
but the problem is that this event is triggered continuously while I'm in the area `Proximity.IMMEDIATE`. I also need to make this event will only work once.

Answer (score 3):

Callback `onBeaconsDiscovered` is invoked every second, not only when beacon is first seen.

If you do not want to trigger code next time, you need to use a boolean guard like `wasSomethingDone`. It is initialized as `false` and set to `true` after your code is executed.

Then just write `if (wasSomethingDone && beacon.getMinor()==22222 && Utils.computeProximity(beacon)== Utils.Proximity.IMMEDIATE) ...`.